# Convert Buffer to Desired Array?

Tags: python, pygithub

I'm using [`pygithub3`](https://github.com/copitux/python-github3) to call an api to receive an organization's repositories, but am getting this result:

```
<pygithub3.core.result.smart.Result object at 0x7f97e9c03d50>
```

I believe this is a buffer object. Why is this happening? I want the result to be

```
['express-file', 'users']
```

My code looks somewhat like this:

```
import pygithub3

auth = dict(username="******", password="******") # I hashed these for SO.
gh = pygithub3.Github(**auth)

repos = gh.repos.list_by_org(org="incrosoft", type="all")
print repos
```

How would I get my desired output? Is it possible? Is there something to turn it into my desired array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the docstring of [the `Result` class](https://github.com/copitux/python-github3/blob/master/pygithub3/core/result/smart.py), you'll see that one can obtain a list by calling `your_result.all()`.

If you type `help(pygithub3.core.result.smart.Result)` in your Python interpreter session (with `pygithub3` imported), you'll see this docstring printed, so you don't need to check the source each time.

Comment: Ok, that gave me a list, `[<Repo (express-file)>, <Repo (users)>]`, but it's still in a Buffer. How do I De-Buffer it?

Comment: @bjskistad, what kind of 'buffer' are you talking about? Please [read the docs](http://pygithub3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html#) first.

Comment: Instead of appearing as strings, they are appearing as the, thing, in the list I just specified.

Comment: @bjskistad, well, there's no other way to know how to convert a `Repo` to a string except simply wandering through the docs and then through the code. Right now, I don't see any kind of `__str__` method or `name` member variable in the `Repo` class.